# Shorthand for "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER" data type name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

The data type keyword "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER" is a chore to type.  I want a shorthand replacement.

At first glance, it seems that SSMS provides two; the words "GUID" and "UID" are both rendered in blue in the query editor (using the default syntax color scheme).

But they are not listed as reserved or future keywords in Microsoft Docs.  I tried to use them like non-reserved data type keywords (such as "DATE" or "INT")

```
Declare @guid uid;
```

and got this error message:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type uid.
> Parameter or variable '@guid' has an invalid data type.

I can create a UDT for UNIQUEIDENTIFIER named "UID".  The result appears to behave as a non-reserved keyword:

```
Create Type [uid] From uniqueidentifier null;
GO
Declare @guid uid = newid();
Print @guid;
GO
```

> B398DA7A-0DF2-49B6-8415-82D31EAA9013

So I have two questions.

1. Are the words "GUID" and "UID" actually keywords, or does SSMS color them for a different reason?
2. What considerations/risks might come with using the words "GUID" or "UID" as UDT names?  I'm mostly worried about future tSQL language compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you the *why* behind Microsoft included `GUID` and `UID` in their reserved words list, but they have which is why they're color coded as blue in **SSMS**. Probably for future proofing in case they do decide to actually implement them as functional keywords or to match other database systems standards, but at this time I don't know of any functional purpose to those two words.

It's best practice and recommended to avoid using reserved words when naming things to avoid any potential complications, which for those two words are unknown at this time, and will depend on if Microsoft ever does implement meaning behind them. If you were to use them in your **UDT** name then you should always reference them with the square brackets to minimize potential issues down the road. But my personal recommendation is to avoid them all together and pick a different name such as `UG`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I suppose you're right that it's still better to play it safe even if there's no formal "why" from MS.  I was hoping to make use of the coloring for "UID", but I just realized I can probably change my SSMS settings for UDT color.

Comment: @KevinP No problem, always better to play it safe and follow best practice over *laziness* (which as developers we all are :). Yup, if you like the color coding, you can definitely adjust the settings in SSMS so it flags your UDT and color codes it accordingly too. :)

Comment: Don't trust the pretty colors in SSMS. Neither `GUID` nor `UID` is in the [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) list, present or future.

Comment: @DanGuzman Neither is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER :-/

Comment: @FernandoSibaja, good point. SQL Server data type names are not necessarily reserved because they are not keywords .

Comment: @DanGuzman A minor distinction that perhaps isn't clear by my verbiage but that's why I purposefully chose not to say *reserved **keywords*** in my answer, rather I used *reserved **words*** because someone on the **SSMS** team at some point made a decision to include those words in **SSMS's** reserved word list for highlighting, despite them not actually presently being reserved keywords in the T-SQL language. Which I would again speculate their subjective decision was based on the possibility of those words becoming keywords at some future point. Personally, I'd not take the risk using them.

Comment: @J.D., I personally don't hesitate using SSMS colored words as identifiers unless it's a documented current or future reserved (key)word. The database engine dev team is very hesitant to introduce new reserved ones (e.g. consider `THROW` should have been made one). I could be wrong but doubt the SSMS team has insight into the future beyond the documented future reserved keywords.

Comment: @DanGuzman Fair enough and to each their own. You're probably right that the **SSMS** team doesn't have much more insight than what's already documented, but I personally still rather play it safe, since in the best case they randomly chose to highlight the word `GUID` and in a not so best case scenario they actually had a reason to do so. But even in the best case that it was random, I could still see use in Microsoft adopting `GUID` as something more purposeful one day just because of its use in other contexts...but who knows, maybe one day my suggestion of `UG` will be a keyword too. :)

Answer (score 2):

The words `guid` and `uid` are coloured like any other object or **possible column** in a SQL statement in SSMS.

When typing out the columns in the following statement, each column is coloured blue, because it is a column from the tables I am referencing.

```
SELECT sao.name AS object_name,
       sao.type_desc AS object_type,
       sac.name AS column_name
FROM   sys.all_columns sac
       JOIN sys.all_objects sao
            ON  sac.object_id = sao.object_id
WHERE  sac.name LIKE 'guid'
       OR  sac.name LIKE 'uid'
```

Coloured as per my SSMS:

[image: colour coded statement in SSMS]

The above statement queries all objects in the sys views `all_objects` and `all_columns` and displays the corresponding object type.

> ```
> +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+
> |             object_name              |           object_type            | column_name |
> +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+
> | sysguidrefs                          | SYSTEM_TABLE                     | guid        |
> | sysobjects                           | VIEW                             | uid         |
> | sysusers                             | VIEW                             | uid         |
> | systypes                             | VIEW                             | uid         |
> | sysprotects                          | VIEW                             | uid         |
> | sysprocesses                         | VIEW                             | uid         |
> | cryptographic_providers              | VIEW                             | guid        |
> | syscacheobjects                      | VIEW                             | uid         |
> | fn_trace_gettable                    | SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION | GUID        |
> | dm_cryptographic_provider_properties | VIEW                             | guid        |
> | dm_xe_packages                       | VIEW                             | guid        |
> +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+
> ```

As you can see, there are a couple of columns named either `guid` or `uid` in a SQL Server instance, that could possibly be referenced in a statement and **this is why SSMS will colour code them blue**.

Comment: I think when you said "*any other object or **possible column***" you actually possibly meant "*any other **system** object or possible **system** column*"?...as user defined columns are by default black colored in a SQL query with the out-of-the-box settings in **SSMS**.

Comment: @J.D: Thanks for noticing the fine-tuning.

Comment: @JohnK.N., An interesting observation that may explain `uid` and `guid`. But further tuning is needed, as not **any** possible system column is colored blue.

Ex. twin sys cols `precision` (blue) and `scale` (black). Only `precision` is a reserved keyword.

Maybe there is no unpublished _non-reserved_ (key)words list, and it just comes down to arbitrary choices by SSMS team? I know I can't always explain my personal coding style in a systematic way.

Side note, sys col `uid` is `smallint`, `guid` is `uniqueidentifier`.
Side side note, Uid and Guid are my favorite Tolkien dwarves.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across another partial answer as to why `guid` gets color.  It *is* a keyword used in ODBC escape sequences.

[Martin Smith - Example Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428636/5982751)

[MS Docs - ODBC SQL Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/sql-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15)

I haven't tracked down an answer for `uid` yet, but at least my confidence is restored in Microsoft (perhaps foolishly) that there is meaning behind the colorization, not mere whim.